# How to resolve ImportError: cannot import name 'Box' from 'bokeh.models'?

Tags: python, bokeh, importerror, geoviews

I'm trying to change the coordinate reference system `crs` to a tile provider in bokeh and I was suggested to use geoviews but after install it I get this error

```
import geoviews as gv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geoviews/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from holoviews import (extension, help, opts, output, renderer, Store, # noqa (API import)
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/holoviews/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .annotators import annotate                         # noqa (API import)
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/holoviews/annotators.py", line 10, in <module>
    from panel.pane import PaneBase
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import layout # noqa
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/layout/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .accordion import Accordion # noqa
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/layout/accordion.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import NamedListPanel
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/layout/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..io.model import hold
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/io/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..config import config
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/config.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .io.notebook import load_notebook
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/io/notebook.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .embed import embed_state
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/io/embed.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .model import add_to_doc, diff
  File "/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/panel/io/model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from bokeh.models import Box, ColumnDataSource, Model
ImportError: cannot import name 'Box' from 'bokeh.models' (/home/kevin1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bokeh/models/__init__.py)
```

I've install HoloViews and reinstall bokeh
`conda install -c bokeh bokeh`
`conda install -c "bokeh/label/dev" bokeh`
but nothing

Comment: Usually this means bokeh isn't installed in the same environment as you are running, or has the wrong version. Try "import bokeh", and if that fails, install a compatible version of bokeh. If it succeeds, check `bokeh.__version__`; it presumably won't be a version compatible with your installed version of Panel.

Comment: At the moment `panel` is not compatible with the lateset version of `bokeh`. This is an issue with work in progress. See [isse #4097](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/4097).

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I had installed `jupyter_bokeh`.  Trying to re-install regular bokeh didn't fix it. Upgrading bokeh didn't help.

Seems to be that HoloViews relies on Panel which requires `bokeh < 2.5.0, >= 2.4.0`. The warning I got from `pip` read:

```
panel 0.14.4 requires bokeh<2.5.0,>=2.4.0, but you have bokeh 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

So, downgrading to `bokeh==2.4.0` solved the problem for me.

Comment: The version `bokeh==2.4.3` should work, too.